# FOSUserBundle override Login logic

Tags: authentication, overriding, fosuserbundle

I have override my Login form, so I want login by `mobileNumber`, not by username and password.

This is the template:

```
{% if error %}
      <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
{% if csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
{% endif %}

     <div class="main-text">Войти</div>

     <div class="text-description-mobile-phone">Мобильный телефон</div>
     <input type="text" name="mobileNumber" placeholder="+7(999) 123-45-67" class="info-input" required="required" />

     <div class="text-description-password">Код из СМС</div>
     <input type="text" name="code" placeholder="9876" class="info-input" required="required" />

     <div class="line"></div>

     <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'Войти'|trans }}" class="enter-button"/>
</form>
```

Where does the login logic take place?
Where can I add checking of my own field?
How can I override user identification?
Can you provide an example?

Comment: Shouldn't it be tagged with `twig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the Internet. If someone will face the same problem, you can find solution there: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/459/how-to-authenticate-login-manually-an-user-in-a-controller-with-or-without-fosuserbundle-on-symfony-3

Or in russian : http://fkn.ktu10.com/?q=node/9574